# Eagle CAD Multiple individual parts in one device

Tags: components, eaglecad, library, device, cad

Good day,

I am trying to place multiple parts in one device. My use case is a foot print for a XBee chip. The device has two identical 10 pin 2mm SMT headers ([NPPN101BFLC-RC: digikey link](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sullins-connector-solutions/NPPN101BFLC-RC/S5901-10-ND/810012)). There is not a "package" that would allow the placement of two individual parts (export smt placements). Is there a way to achieve this design approach? Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: If you wanted them as two separate parts, you would simply add two copies. You wouldn't want one single part to come in as multiple pieces as otherwise you can't guarantee they are the correct distance apart or aligned correctly.

Answer (score 2):

For simple CAD management and hand assembly, this process would work:

1. Find or create the footprint for the 10 pin, 2mm connector you plan to use
2. Copy the footprint twice into a new footprint, then assign the correct pin numbers and ensure that the relative positions/alignments are correct for your module

Then you can use that footprint with whatever symbol you have created for the XBee module.

However, as pointed out in the comments, this prevents the individual headers from having accessible data for automated assembly. Making this data available requires a more complicated CAD process and attention to multi-part components.

1. Find or create the footprint for the 10 pin, 2mm connector you plan to use
2. Make two copies of the footprint, then add silkscreen to distinguish the left/right connectors. Also, adding data on a mechanical layer to indicate the required spacing between the two headers would give more immediate context in layout.
3. Create schematic symbols for the two 'halves' of the component. Make sure you have a comment indicating that each symbol is only half of the required connectivity.
4. When you use the symbols in your schematic, place comments in the schematic that there are two footprints that require an exact relative positions in layout.
5. During initial footprint placement in layout, find the two halves and set their coordinates as desired on the board. I'm not sure if Eagle can do this, but, if you can, then "union" the two footprints into one object or lock both of their coordinates on the board. This should help prevent accidentally moving only one of the footprints and ending up with an Arduino-like spacing error in your design.

Comment: My interpretation of what your saying is:
1. Make the footprint (done that)
2. Make a device for the xbee
3. Place two of the headers in the device (spaced properly)

Comment: I though about your answer again and came up with this: I was thinking about this approach but I was not sure that the manufacturer would be able to place the two parts since a mountsmt.ulp would use the center of the footprint (the xbee not the two headers) as its coordinate. Correct me if I am mistaken. The edit tool will not allow you to make edits after 5 mins...

Comment: @Mrkelley I did not think of the manufacturing process needs for placing these connectors. This is definitely a problem with the monolithic device footprint.

Comment: @Mrkelley I have updated my answer with additional content.